# How to determine which Tile definition a JSP page uses?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, struts, tiles

I'm pretty new to Java, and just encountered a strange problem.  Previously, everything was working fine and I don't know what I did to screw it up (I know, everyone says that).  What's happening is that I am working on a web app that uses Apache Struts (1.x) and Tiles, and when I go to a page in the web browser, it seems to be using a different Tile definition than it used to.

Here's the relevant lines from tiles-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration//EN"
       "http://supplies.ur.com/dtds/tiles-config_1_1.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
  <definition name=".default" path="/template_new.jsp">
    <put name="title" value="[Company Web App Name]" direct="true"/>
    <put name="customerInfo" value="/customerInfo.jsp" direct="false"/>
    <put name="smallBody" value="" direct="true"/>
    <put name="menu" value="" direct="true"/>
    <put name="quickMenu" value="/quickMenu.jsp" direct="false"/>
    <put name="adminMenu" value="/adminMenu.jsp" direct="false"/>
    <put name="message" value="/message.jsp" direct="false"/>
    <put name="body" value="" direct="true"/>
    <put name="helpAvailable" value="yes" direct="false"/>
    <put name="feedbackAvailable" value="yes" direct="false"/>
    <put name="problemReportingAvailable" value="yes" direct="false"/>
    <put name="newFeaturesAvailable" value="yes" direct="false"/>
  </definition>
  <definition name=".empty" path="/blank.jsp">
    <put name="title" value="[Company Web App Name]" direct="true"/>
    <put name="customerInfo" value="/customerInfo.jsp" direct="false"/>
    <put name="quickMenu" value="/quickMenu.jsp" direct="false"/>
    <put name="message" value="/message.jsp" direct="false"/>
    <put name="body" value="" direct="true"/>
    <put name="footer" value="/footer2.jsp" direct="false"/>
    <put name="helpAvailable" value="yes" direct="false"/>
    <put name="feedbackAvailable" value="yes" direct="false"/>
    <put name="problemReportingAvailable" value="yes" direct="false"/>
    <put name="newFeaturesAvailable" value="yes" direct="false"/>
  </definition>
  <!-- Forgot to include the .rentalHistoryByType definition... -->
  <definition name=".rentalHistoryByType" extends=".default">
    <put name="title" value="Equipment Rental History By Type" direct="true"/>
    <put name="smallBody" value="/rentalHistoryByType_Search.jsp" direct="false"/>
    <put name="body" value="/rentalHistoryByType.jsp" direct="false"/>
  </definition>
  <!-- Added for CoolBeans -->
  <definition name=".customerChoose" extends=".default">
    <put name="title" value="Choose a customer" direct="true"/>
    <put name="quickMenu" value="" direct="true"/>
    <put name="smallBody" value="/customerChoose_Search.jsp" direct="false"/>
    <put name="body" value="/customerChoose.jsp" direct="false"/>
  </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Here's the relevant lines from struts-config.xml:

```
<action path="/rentalHistoryByType" type="com.[company name deleted].etrieveit.actions.RentalHistoryByTypeAction">
  <forward name="customerNotSelected" path="/customerChoose.do" />
  <forward name="success" path=".rentalHistoryByType" />
</action>
<!-- Added for CoolBeans -->
<action path="/customerChoose" type="com.[company name deleted].etrieveit.actions.CustomerChooseAction">
  <forward name="success" path=".customerChoose" />
</action>
```

The page I'm going to in the browser is "[path]/rentalHistoryByType.do", the body of which is built with rentalHistoryByType_Search.jsp and rentalHistoryByType.jsp.  The way I found the problem is that jQuery suddenly stopped working on the page when it had been working fine before.  On viewing source, I found that rentalHistoryByType.do is being built from blank.jsp, not template_new.jsp.  (template_new.jsp has the script includes for jQuery, whereas blank.jsp does not, and other details in the page source match blank.jsp exactly as well.)

My question is, how can I tell which Tile definition a page is going to use when it gets requested and how can I change it?  And/or, what might cause a page to use a different Tile definition than it was apparently using before?

Sorry if my terminology is wrong or confusing, I'm new enough to Java that I don't really know what I'm doing yet...

Comment: Can you paste the section of the struts-config.xml that has the rentalHistoryByType action defined?

Comment: Can you also paste the customerChoose.do action in your struts-config.xml? What you have pasted so far should lead to template_new.jsp not blank.

Comment: I added the customerChoose sections from struts-config and tiles-config above.

Comment: hmm strange both of these extends .default which should be template_new.jsp.

Comment: I'm basically stumped.  I had a problem before (also answered on Stack Overflow) where NetBeans for some reason had moved a file to another location and wasn't refreshing it when compiling, but for this one I unzipped the .war files that I copy over to JBoss and looked in them, and the struts-config and tiles-config files in there are correct.  I've rebooted and cleared all my browser history to make sure the cache is clear, restarted the JBoss server a bunch of times, etc.  I don't know what else there is to do. :(

Comment: Can you also make sure that template_new.jsp is located at the same level as your rentalHistoryByType_Search.jsp (folder structure wise)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer; it was apparently a caching issue.  I stopped JBoss, deleted the contents of JBoss's \server\default\tmp and \server\default\work folders, and restarted JBoss, and now it's working correctly...

Answer (score 1):

There should be a struts config file (named struts-config.xml typically) that has a mapping of actions to definitions, e.g. it would contain

```
<action path="/home"
  type="com.myco.MyHomeAction">
  <forward name="home/landing"
    path="home.definition"/>
</action>
```

Comment: Here's the bit from the struts-config.xml referring to rentalHistoryByType: <action path="/rentalHistoryByType" type="com.[CompanyName].etrieveit.actions.RentalHistoryByTypeAction">  <forward name="customerNotSelected" path="/customerChoose.do" />  <forward name="success" path=".rentalHistoryByType" />  </action> (sorry, code formatting doesn't work in comments)  I don't see anything referring to blank in there...?

Comment: Where does path=".rentalHistoryByType" get mapped? I don't see it in your tiles-definition xml.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  From tiles-config.xml: <definition name=".rentalHistoryByType" extends=".default">  <put name="title" value="Equipment Rental History By Type" direct="true"/>  <put name="smallBody" value="/rentalHistoryByType_Search.jsp" direct="false"/>  <put name="body" value="/rentalHistoryByType.jsp" direct="false"/>  </definition>

Comment: @CoolBeans: Argh, just noticed you're looking for the struts-config bit, not the tiles-config bit.  I'll edit that into my question post above.